# Get Istio Ingress Gateway Endpoint With Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, istio, istio-gateway

I deployed Istio in AWS EKS, and I would like to get the endpoint of the automatically created load balancers to use them in other resources, like DNS entries and such. Is there any way to gather them?
I tried data "external" to run kubectl, but does not really work well.

Any ideas?

Comment: when you say external, do you mean this? https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns

Comment: No, I meant External data source https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source

Comment: @TamásJuhász Can you add the code you have? I think it could be available by using attributes that get exported when a resource is created.

Comment: That is the thing, Istio ingresses are not created via TF, but Istio operator. Dunno how I could gather this information, as there is no resource for it.
I tried this, but it does not work:
data "external" "public-istio-ingressgateway" {
  program = ["kubectl", "get services -n istio-system | grep '^public-istio-ingressgateway'"]
}

Comment: Sure, but there is some istio code?

Comment: No TF code, Istio is installed by istioctl and operator. Now we are experimenting with Helm charts.

Answer (score 2):

I found what I needed. kubernetes_service data source

```
data "kubernetes_service" "istio-ingressgateway" {
  metadata {
    name      = "istio-ingressgateway"
    namespace = "istio-system"
  }
}

data "kubernetes_service" "public-istio-ingressgateway" {
  metadata {
    name      = "public-istio-ingressgateway"
    namespace = "istio-system"
  }
}

output "istio-ingressgateway" {
  value = data.kubernetes_service.istio-ingressgateway.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname
}

output "public-istio-ingressgateway" {
  value = data.kubernetes_service.public-istio-ingressgateway.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/service